# Volume of Revolution. Am I doing it right?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the volume when revolving the region bounded by $y=1-\frac{1}{2}x$, $y=0$, and $x=0$ about the line $ x=-2$?

Would it be $x=2-2y$
so radius $r(y) = 2-2y -(-2) $ => $r(y)= 4-2y$

$π\int (4-2y)^2 dy$ ?

What would be my limits of integration? Would it be from 0 to 2?? yes?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You've done everything right except for the integration limits. Since you are integrating over $y$, the limits should be from $y=0$ to where the given line intersects the $y$-axis, which is *not* $y=2$.